# How do I change color with onmouseover?

Tags: javascript

I wonder how I can do those 2 functions into 1 function instead.

```
 function test1() {
                document.getElementById('div1').style.color = 'red';
            }
 function test2() {
                document.getElementById('div1').style.color = 'blue';
            }


    <div onmouseover="test1()" onmouseout ="test2()" id="div1">
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

pass the object and color to the `test` method

```
 function test(thisObj, color) 
 {
    thisObj.style.color = color;
 }

 <div onmouseover="test(this, 'red')" onmouseout ="test(this, 'green')" id="div1"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

you can achieve this with just css

https://jsfiddle.net/dango_x_daikazoku/404o04co/1/

```
#test1{
  color:red;
  cursor:default;
}
#test1:hover{
  color:blue;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do with JavaScript you can do in this way.

JS :

```
window.onload  = function(){
        var htmlDiv = document.getElementById("div1");

        htmlDiv.addEventListener('mouseover',function(){

          htmlDiv.style.color = "red";    
        })

         htmlDiv.addEventListener('mouseout',function(){  
           htmlDiv.style.color = "blue";    
        })
      }
```

HTML :

```
<style>
      #div1{
        width:100px;
        height : 100ppx;
        border :1px solid black;
      }
      #div1 { 
        color:blue; 
      }
    </style>
```

Here is the [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/b85803m5l5gEb2Gx8dmQ?p=preview)

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend [CSS :hover Selector](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_hover.asp)

If you want to change class from javascript, i would recommend jQuery:

[jQuery addClass() Method](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/html_addclass.asp),

[jQuery removeClass() Method](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/html_removeclass.asp),

[hover()](https://api.jquery.com/hover/)

[mouseover()](https://api.jquery.com/mouseover/)

[hasClass()](https://api.jquery.com/hasclass/)

As for your request to do this with one function, you could write:

```
function manageHoverColor(){
   if( $("#hoverTestDiv").hasClass("mouseHovered") ){
      $( "#hoverTestDiv" ).removeClass('mouseHovered');
   }else{
      $( "#hoverTestDiv" ).addClass('mouseHovered');
   }
}


$( "#hoverTestDiv" ).mouseover(manageHoverColor);
$( "#hoverTestDiv" ).mouseout(manageHoverColor);
```

or you could do:

```js
$( "#hoverTestDiv" ).mouseover(function() {
    $( "#hoverTestDiv" ).addClass('mouseHovered');
  });

$( "#hoverTestDiv" ).mouseout(function() {
     $( "#hoverTestDiv" ).removeClass('mouseHovered');
  });
```

```css
.ordinaryText {
    color: #00FF00;
}

.ordinaryText.mouseHovered {
    color: #FF0000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="hoverTestDiv" class="ordinaryText" > I am div to test jQuery mouse hover <div>
```